# Why doesn't the nested component render as a slottable custom element?

Tags: custom-element, svelte

Are there limitations to compiling Svelte components as custom elements? For instance, are we able to nest components? And fill slots in those nested components?

I'm having trouble using a Svelte component as a custom element in my older Vue app.

I've got a Select and a Modal component in this simplified example: https://svelte.dev/repl/4d4ad853f8a14c6aa27f6baf33751eb8?version=3.6.4

I'm then compiling these with a standard-fare rollup.config.js:

```
export default {
  input: "src/components.js",
  output: [
    // ...
    { file: "dist/index.min.js", format: "umd", name }
  ],
  plugins: [
    svelte({
      dev: !production,
      customElement: true,
      // ...
    }),
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    !production && livereload("public"),
    production && terser()
  ],
  // ...
};
```

Then I go to use the custom elements. On click of the `<conversational-select>`, I get markup that looks like the following:

```
<conversational-select label="Domains" firstvaluelabel="All Domains">
    <!-- shadow-root -->
    <style>...</style>
    <span class="select" >
        <div class="select-value">Governance Board</div>
        <div class="select-label" ></div>
    </span>
    <!-- The below div is the appropriate markup for Modal but the style isn't inlined and isn't slotted.
    <!-- maybe because it didn't append as <sk-modal>?  -->
    <div ><slot></slot></div>
</conversational-select>
```

The "Modal" is sort-of rendering. But it doesn't fill the slot with `span .chip`s. Doesn't inline the styles like the `conversational-select` does. Doesn't seem to attach its own event listeners. But does seem to create the fade transition thanks to Svelte's `transition:fade` directive.

I can reproduce this with a vanilla html file, so it's not Vue's fault.

Am I breaking some known rule with custom elements, butting up against the limitations of Svelte's custom element compilation, or just mistaken somewhere?

Comment: may it be related https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/3128 ?

Comment: @skyboyer Thank you, I think you're probably right. The author of that issue cam-stitt came to the conclusion that mirrors my problem. When I add the child custom-element at runtime via the browser console the mount methods run and everything.

Position this as a known issue and I'll accept yours as the best answer to date.

Comment: have you found any workaround so far?

Answer (score 0):

I was the author of the Svelte github issue that has been mentioned. I believe that I have a fix [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/pull/3136). There were a few issues that existed:

- `slotted` was never set
- "nested" elements were not being added correctly

I expect the Svelte authors to make changes to my pull request, but if you want to use it, you can:

- Clone my branch
- Run `npm && npm build && npm link`
- Go to your project and run `npm link svelte`